# Script Or API way in Cisco ACI to check interface flap statistics

Tags: cisco

Would you have an option to check all the interfaces that is flapping my fabric ? Please help , i'm 1 Month new to this . Thanks.

Comment: Scripting and programming are off limits here but we can maybe help other ways if you provide make/model info and sanitized configs, and tell us more about what’s going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with EEM(Embedded Event Manager). The EEM(Embedded Event manager is a software component of cisco IOS, XR, and NX-OS that makes life easier for administrators by tracking and classifying events that take place on a router and providing notification options for those events. EEM allows you to automate tasks, perform minor enhancements and create workarounds.

Check this **[port-flapping-detect](https://github.com/sbarissonmez/port-flapping-detect)** on my GitHub.